# How to ensure not to modify a parameter passed by reference in PHP

Tags: php, reference, constants

In C++ you could do like this, to ensure that the parameter you passed by reference is not going to be modified:

```
void function Foo(const &param){}
```

How can i do the same in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant, if you want just read it create copy of that variable, but overall if you dont need references dont use them, as it looks in this case. References wont give you any performance benefits on php.

Comment: You actually can do references like `&$param`. You also have to do & when passing the variable too.

Comment: What you mean when you said "References wont give you any performance benefits on php"? Do they use memory?

Comment: Because php is optimized that way "copy-on-write", you can read more about references here: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html